# How can I polyfill a CSS background-size transition in IE 10 - 11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to introduce some animation on hover to a few elements of a site.

I noticed that it was looking a bit glitchy in IE 10 and IE 11 and through a bit of research found out that those browsers don't support the CSS `transition` property for `background-size`!

OK, fine, but MS have also removed conditional comments from those browsers, so: any ideas how I can give IE 10 and IE 11 a simplified transition (keeping the `background-image` the same size) and yet still keep the full animation for those that can?

**CSS**

```
.home .hero a.animate  {
    background-image: url("/images/home/question.gif"),
                      url("/images/home/person.gif"),
                      url("/images/home/bulb.gif"), 
                      url("/images/home/person-m.gif"),
                      url("/images/home/person-f.gif");
    background-position: 51% 14.5em,
                         50% 13em, 
                         51% 14.5em, 
                         90% 7em,
                         10% 7.5em;
    background-size: 10% auto,
                     40% auto, 
                     10% auto,
                     30% auto, 
                     29% auto;
}

.home .hero a.animate:hover {
    background-image: url("/images/home/bulb.gif"),
                      url("/images/home/person.gif"),
                      url("/images/home/question.gif"), 
                      url("/images/home/person-m.gif"),
                      url("/images/home/person-f.gif");
    background-position: 51% 8em,
                         50% 12em, 
                         51% 8em, 
                         85% 9em,
                         15% 9.5em;
    background-size: 10% auto,
                     38% auto, 
                     10% auto,
                     35% auto, 
                     34% auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <a class="animate" href="#">
        <h2>Consultancy</h2>
        <p>unbiased and totally independent</p>

        <span class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Find out more</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.